# getting runtime error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.PropertyTypeDescriptor

Tags: spring, spring-security, primefaces, ehcache

I have  integrated SWF 2.2.1,Primefaces 2.2.1,JSF 2,Spring Security 3,Spring 3.1.0M1I and  EhCache.

I am able to get the first page of my application but on submitting the page getting following weird error. I googled it , did not get any information on this.

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet threw
>   exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.PropertyTypeDescriptor.(Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;Lorg/springframework/core/MethodParameter;)V
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectivePropertyAccessor.canRead(ReflectivePropertyAccessor.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:71)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.setValue(CompoundExpression.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.setValue(SpelExpression.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.setValue(SpringELExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:391)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:386)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:254)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:218)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Here is my maven dependency tree

```
D:\Tutorial\simpleWeb>mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building simpleWeb Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:2.2.RC2 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ simpleWeb ---
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:2.2.RC2
[INFO] com.mytutorial:simpleWeb:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.M1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.M1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:org.springframework.binding:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:org.springframework.expression:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:org.springframework.js:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.webflow:org.springframework.js.resources:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:org.springframework.webflow:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:org.springframework.faces:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-aspects:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.castor:castor:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml-schema:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-core:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.3-b05:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.0.3-b05:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:com.springsource.slf4j.log4j:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.log4j:com.springsource.org.apache.log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:com.springsource.slf4j.api:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:2.2.RC2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-terracotta:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.188s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 01 14:38:05 IST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you post the output of 'mvn dependency:tree'?

Comment: Is it closed? Can you please tell me the reason, so that I cant repeat it in future. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean if it's closed? the question is not closed if that's what you were asking. i don't know why you received the downvote, wasn't me, though i'd still need the output of dependency:tree to be able to help, you probably have some conflicting versions of your jars but i cannot say which ones.

Comment: I have edited the question and posted it.

Comment: Thanks abalogh. I was resolving that only. I removed the conflicting dependencies.It worked !!! yipeee :-)
This is a typical scenario where I need all dependencies of Spring 3.0.4 release and only spring-context and spring-context-support of 3.1.0.M1(as I am using caching capabilites of this new release).

Answer (score 4):

I'm just guessing here but you depend on `org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.M1` and `org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE`. My guess is that those version numbers should be equal.

If there is no 3.1 milestone for core, at least try the latest release 3.0.5.